# Groupable property not working for kendo ui grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have set the value for groupable as true, even then I am not able to group it. When I drag the column header nothing happens.

I am using jquery version as 1.8.3. I tried with jquery.1.9.1.min.js

Please if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Check here an example http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/qyzJR/

Comment: I have used it same way as the example, but not sure why it is not working. Will check again. I have used           
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "MasterColID"
                }
            },
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            change: onChange,
            scrollable: true,  
            height:100,
            selectable: "row",
            dataBound: RowDataBound}).data("kendoGrid"); Would it because some other attribute is causing this behavior. Please correct me.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/sats/e8HMZ/

Comment: @user2117983 your example doesn't work due to JavaScript errors. Fix them.

Comment: sorry for that. But seems like this is not required as of now for me. But thanks everyone for your all suggestions and help